# We rejected myApp, with package name com.example.myApp, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy

Tags: android, cordova

I was getting below message :

> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as
>   soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>
> Vulnerability : Apache Cordova    APK Version(s) : 13 The vulnerabilities
>   were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.
>
> You can find information about how to upgrade in this Google Help
>   Center article.

I checked, my app's Cordova Android version was 3.5 then I upgraded Android version to 4.1.1. But my app was not working so I created whole new app with the same package name.

Earlier my app's version was 13, after upgrading I updated it to 14. I was able to update the app on Play Store. But now my problem is, the devices which contains the older version of the app not getting option to UPDATE the app. I have to uninstall the app to get the updated version.

Comment: what's your mobile android version ?

Comment: Probably, it is due to difference in signature by which you created apk.

Comment: @TGMCians Signature? I'm not getting... please explain. Thanks